# Error with a predefined name in core data model

Tags: objective-c, json, mapping

I have a problem with my core data model. In my entity I have an attribute description. But when I want to set this attribute, I get the following error. For not getting this error I set its name to genk_description.

> Property name clashes with a method implemented by NSManagedObject or NSObject

The name of this attribute should be description because I am fetching my data from a webmethod that gives back data in JSON format.

So I probably do some mapping. But don't have a clue how I can do that. This is what I am doing in code so far. Here I define my attribute.

```
#define NEWS_DESCRIPTION @"genk_description"
```

Here I also need to do some mapping so that NEWS_DESCRIPTION @"genk_description" becomes NEWS_DESCRIPTION @"description"

Does anybody have an idea how I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

you cant give a property the name `description` because it is a method on [NSObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSObject). As `NSObject` is the root object you can't use the name `description` for any instance variable in Objective-C.

Just avoid naming it in that way.

When you import your data, store the "description" value returned from the web service into a variable with some other name in your core data object.